# JSON stringify is showing object object after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, json

[image][image]inputting the data is fine, submitting is fine. But, if I refresh, everything that was inputted displays as object object. Any idea's why?

In addition to this, each input creates table data but seperately rather than in a table and each input puts each newly created data side by side whereas I want them to space-around like justify-content: space-around. But it doesn't seem to be doing that

Still new to JS. I couldn't find exactly what i'm doing wrong. JSON stringify is still a new practice for me too. So, I am unsure if what I have done is correct.

EDIT ------------------------
Can anyone explain what is happening with the formatting after a refresh ?

html

```
    <h1>Library</h1>
  
    <div id="login" class="login-btn">
        <button class="User" id = "login">login</button>
    </div>
    
   
    
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
   
    
<form id="form" action="">

    <input  class="input" type="text" id="input-title" placeholder="Title" required />
    <input class="input" type="text" id="input-author" placeholder="Author" required/>
    <input class="input" type="number" id="input-number" placeholder="Pages" required />
     <input value="Submit" id="submitbtn" class="submit" type="submit">
    
        </form>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"><span> Check me if you read the book</span>
<table id="table">
    
</table>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js

//buttons

```
const buttonLogin = document.getElementById("login")

const table = document.getElementById("table")
const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear")

const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitbtn")
const form = document.getElementById("form")
const inputTitle = document.getElementById("input-title")
const inputAuthor = document.getElementById("input-author")
const inputNumber = document.getElementById("input-number")

//array local storage
  
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
  : []



localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))

const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))

const createBook = (text, text1, text2) => {
    const tble = document.createElement('table')
    const td = document.createElement('td')
    const td2 = document.createElement('td')
    const td3 = document.createElement('td')
    
    td.textContent = text
    td.style.color = ('black')
    td.style.border = ('solid')
    td.style.borderColor =('blueviolet')
    
    
    
    td2.textContent = text1
    td2.style.color = ('black')
    td2.style.border = ('solid')
    td2.style.borderColor = ('blueviolet')
    
    td3.textContent = text2
    td3.style.color = ('black')
    td3.style.border = ('solid')
    td3.style.borderColor =('blueviolet')
    table.appendChild(td)
    table.appendChild(td2)
    table.appendChild(td3)
  }


  form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    //for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    itemsArray.push(inputTitle, inputAuthor, inputNumber)
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
    createBook(inputTitle.value, inputAuthor.value, inputNumber.value)
    inputTitle.value =  ''
    inputAuthor.value=  ''
    inputNumber.value=  ''
  //  }  
})

  
data.forEach ((item) => {
    createBook(item)
})


  //clear list
  clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    localStorage.clear()
    while (table.firstChild) {
      table.removeChild(table.firstChild)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a *minimal example*? I'm sure we don't need all this code to reproduce the issue…

Comment: sorry, yes. Just did it.

Comment: Why do you need both `data` and `itemsArray`? Aren't they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the values of the inputs, not the input elements themselves. And the values for a single item should be collected together into an array or object.

```
itemsArray.push([inputTitle.value, inputAuthor.value, inputNumber.value])
```

Also, when you process the data, you need to spread the array into separate arguments to `createBook()`.

```
data.forEach ((item) => {
    createBook(...item)
})
```

Comment: Also, when you process the data, you need to spread the array into separate arguments to createBook().

I don't think I understand - "createBook(...item)"

Comment: That's shorthand for `createBook(item[0], item[1], item[2])`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Thank you and especially for the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

i think it's relate to this line

```
itemsArray.push(inputTitle, inputAuthor, inputNumber)

// where 
const inputTitle = document.getElementById("input-title")
const inputAuthor = document.getElementById("input-author")
const inputNumber = document.getElementById("input-number")

// should be below if you don't want printout [object Object]
itemsArray.push(inputTitle.value, inputAuthor.value, inputNumber.value)
```

why '[object Object]'

```
var array = []
var anchor = document.createElement('a')
array.push(JSON.stringify(anchor)) // -> ['{}']

var anchor2 = document.createElement('a')
anchor2.textContent = JSON.parse('{}')
anchor2.textContent // -> '[object Object]'
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.